# How to highlight rows or string in one dataframe based off the values of a column in a different datafame?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, pandas-styles

I want to be able take vales from one column of dataframe and find the exact same values in another dataframe to either highlight the whole row or just the string (whatever is easier/possible).

```
dataset1 = {'Gene Name':['ampC','fliC','ompC','fruB','yobH','gltP','ruvA','yacC','folD'],
       'FoldChange':['4.54','5.65','7.89','6.45','10.67','4.63','2.65','9.45','5.79'],
        'pvalue':['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0']}

df1= pd.DataFrame(dataset1)

dataset2 = {'Gene Name':['gltP','ruvA','yacC','folD']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dataset2)
```

If it is possible I would like to make something that would look like either of the bottom examples.

[image: What I would like my dataset to look like]

I've tried a bunch of different stuff but I'm still learning python so not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the genes of `df1` [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) those of `df2`, then [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) your CSS style :

```
m = df1["Gene Name"].isin(df2["Gene Name"])

def fn(ser, how):
    import numpy as np
    return np.where(m, f"{how}: red", "")
    
# choose one of the two
left = df1.style.apply(fn, how="color", subset=["Gene Name"])
right = df1.style.apply(fn, how="background-color")

# .to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False) # to save an Excel
```

Preview of both :

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, they way you wrote the solution was very clear and easy for me to understand.